# How can i remove everything on an image except for the text in python?

Tags: python, image, opencv, image-processing, text

I have an image with measurements that I need to read with python and right now it reads the most text but not all because some lines are in the way. I cant use the original image so I made an image that looks like the one I'm using.

```py
def erode(img):
        kernel = np.ones((3,3), np.uint8)
        eroded = cv2.erode(img, kernel, iterations=1)
        gray = cv2.cvtColor(eroded,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
        edges = cv2.Canny(gray,50,150,apertureSize = 3)
        minLineLength = 10
        maxLineGap = 1
        lines = cv2.HoughLinesP(edges,1,np.pi/180,120,minLineLength,maxLineGap)
        for line in lines:
            for x1,y1,x2,y2 in line:
                cv2.line(eroded,(x1,y1),(x2,y2),(255,255,255),7)
```

I have tried using the `OpenCV` function `houghLinesP` and drawing a line over these but this doesn't remove all lines and still leaves some dots all over the place like this:
[image: img with dots]

what I want is to give something like this as input:
[image: with lines]

and get something like this as an output:
[image: without lines]

the reason I need to remove all the lines but not change the 
text is because I need to save the text coordinates.

Comment: Do you have an example of the code you are using?

Comment: @Barb added it to the post

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The idea is to dilate and connect the text together to form a single contour. From here we can find contours and filter using a minimum threshold area. If it passes this filter then we have a desired text ROI to keep and we draw this ROI onto a mask

[image]

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

image = cv2.imread('3.png')
mask = np.ones(image.shape, dtype=np.uint8) * 255
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
thresh = cv2.threshold(gray, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV + cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]
kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (5,5))
dilate = cv2.dilate(thresh, kernel, iterations=3)

cnts = cv2.findContours(dilate, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
cnts = cnts[0] if len(cnts) == 2 else cnts[1]
for c in cnts:
    area = cv2.contourArea(c)
    if area < 5000:
        x,y,w,h = cv2.boundingRect(c)
        mask[y:y+h, x:x+w] = image[y:y+h, x:x+w]

cv2.imshow('thresh', thresh)
cv2.imshow('dilate', dilate)
cv2.imshow('mask', mask)
cv2.waitKey()
```